# Is there a way to export individual sheets in a excel workbook to separate csv files using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, data-science

I have 5 sheets in an excel workbook. I would like to export each sheet to csv using python libraries.
[This is a sheet showing sales in 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjbZu.jpg). I have named the seets according to the year they represent as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxevN.jpg).

I have read the excel spreadsheet using pandas. I have used the for loop since I am interested in saving the csv file like the_sheet_name.csv. This is my code in a jupyter notebook:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame() 
myfile = 'sampledata.xlsx’ 
xl = pd.ExcelFile(myfile)

for sheet in xl.sheet_names: 
     df_tmp = xl.parse(sheet) 
     print(df_tmp)
     df = df.append(df_tmp, ignore_index=True,sort=False) 
     csvfile = f'{sheet_name}.csv' 
     df.to_csv(csvfile, index=False)
```

Executing the code is producing just one csv file that has the data for all the other sheets. I would like to know if there is a way to customize my code so that I can produce individual sheets e.g sales2011.csv, sales2012.csv and so on.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We ask that you provide a [mcve] with code in the _text_ of your question, not as a picture or link, showing what you've tried based on your own research so that we can help you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sheet_name=None` returns a dictionary of dataframes:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

for sheet_name, data in dfs.items():
    data.to_csv(f"{sheet_name}.csv")
```